# How do I parse an XML file into a ListBox

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, parsing

I am trying to parse this xml file http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml into a ListBox in visual C#, I tried a lot of different methods none of them worked, this is the one that kind of works:

```
XElement element = XElement.Load("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml");
foreach (XElement item in element.Elements("channel")) {
   listBox1.Items.Add(item.Value);
}
```

the only problem is, it loads the
[wrong object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QExSJ.png)
and if I set it to

```
XElement element = XElement.Load("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml");
foreach (XElement item in element.Elements("item")) {
   listBox1.Items.Add(item.Value);
}
```

it loads nothing, what should i do?

Comment: The easiest is probably [DataSet.ReadXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), then you can use different tables, like the `item` table as data source of your ListBox and `title` as display member.

Comment: alright i will try that, thanks!

Comment: @RezaAghaei so i do not seem to understand the documentation... can you give an example on how to use it? i am new to C# and its hard for me to figure out these by myself, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You can use either of the following solutions:

**Using [Linq to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)**

Use [*XElement.Load*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.load?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)* to load the element, then use [*.Descendants("item")*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or [*.Elements("channel").Elements("item")*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to get the specific *item* element:

```
var items = XElement.Load("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml")
    .Descendants("item") // OR Use: .Elements("channel").Elements("item")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        title = x.Element("title").Value,
        description = x.Element("description").Value,
        pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
        link = x.Element("link").Value,
        guid = x.Element("guid").Value,
    }).ToList();

listBox1.DataSource = items;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "title";
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", items, "description");
```

**Using [Load a DataSet from XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/loading-a-dataset-from-xml?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)**

Use [*DataSet.ReadXml*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to load a data set, then you can use different tables, like the *item* table as data source of your ListBox and *title* as DisplayMember.:

```
var ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml");
var items = ds.Tables["item"];
listBox1.DataSource = items;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "title";
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", items, "description");
```

Comment: thanks again, i was trying to figure this out for days!